# What's wrong? C

Tags: c, while-loop, strcmp

I wanna compare an element of a string with a char, what's wrong? i get segmentation fault.

i wanna go trough a string, copyng the part of string until an element of string,  when the element=",", but i'm making something of wrong.

passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
     char palavra[1000],linha[1000];
     int i;

     while(fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), df)!=NULL){

                i=0;
                strcopy(palavra,"0");                    

                while(strcmp(&linha[i],",")!=0){

                    strcpy(&palavra[i],&linha[i]);
                    i++;                    

                }
      printf("%s,",palavra);
      }
```

Comment: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: You don't need `strcmp` to compare chars.  Just compare them directly.

Comment: The title here is to tell us what this question is about. Yours has zero value.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `strcmp` to compare individual `char`, it is meant for comparing full strings.  If you just want to compare individual elements, you would just compare them directly:
`linha[i] == ','`

Same applies for copying a char.

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
           while(linha[i] != ','){

                palavra[i] = linha[i];
                i++;                    

            }
```

Although I am a bit suspicious of `palavra[i]` assignment since that overwrites the strcpy of 0 done before the loop

Answer (score -1):

1. You are passing address, not value `&linha[i]`
2. to use strcmp(), both strings should be null terminated(\0)

So, use if as

```
for( i=0; i < len; i++)          
    if(linha[i]!=',')
```

Comment: should be `!= ','`

Comment: still got "," instead of ','